# backreference and interval brakets doesn't work with MacOS grep

Tags: regex, macos, grep

I am new to shell script and am stuck with using backreference and interval brackets.

I am logging in to my macOSX sierra and the output of who command is like this

```
foo       console  Nov  3 19:06
bar       ttys000  Nov  3 19:06
```

Then when do grep like below,

```
who | grep -G \(o\).*\1
who | grep -G o\{3\}
```

Both return nothing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `who | grep '0\{3\}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first one would work if you put quotes around the Regex pattern to avoid shell interpretation beforehand.

  In the first Regex pattern, `.*`, greedily matches as much as it can, in your case till the last `o`:

  ```
  $ grep -Go '\(o\).*\1' <<<'foo       console  Nov  3 19:06'
  oo       console  No
  ```
- The second pattern, `grep -G o\{3\}` did not match because there is no three consecutive `o`s in the string to match, perhaps you meant to match three `0`s. Again use quotes around the pattern to prevent shell interpretation beforehand:

  ```
  $ grep -Go '0\{3\}' <<<'bar       ttys000  Nov  3 19:06'
  000
  ```